# Fragment does not close

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm creating a fragment which is supposed to act like a menu. I have successfully inflated it to the activity where I wanted it to be, however I now I realise that I cannot close the fragment. Furthermore I am able to scroll the contents of the activity which the fragment is placed over. How can I edit my code in such a way that the fragment will close after an action on the activity is detected, or one of it's contents is clicked?

I created the fragment by simply adding a fragment via new -> Fragment -> Fragment(Blank). I have not touched any of the code and have initialized the fragment like so in a on click:

```
findViewById(R.id.Menu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left);
            MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, menuFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });
```

This is what it looks like, ignore the horrendous design.

[image: two muppets]

Comment: Put the fragment inside DrawerLayout.

Comment: Does not work, I have the same issue.

Comment: set drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START) when drawer items are clicked.

Comment: Where can I set this?

Comment: Whenever any item is clicked of your layout inside drawerlayout.